# Не загружается файл google analytics Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Заметил, что перестал загружаться файл аналитики. На разных сайтах и браузерах. Хром из за этого долго загружает страницу. В чем проблема и как можно исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня касперский режет всякую аналитику и метрику. Слава антивирусам! Может, у вас тоже что-то блокирует?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась сбросом настроек роутера.